# Are $|\pm x\rangle$ and $|\pm y\rangle$ always defined the same way for a two-level system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, two-level-system

I'm a little confused about the definitions of the states $|+x\rangle$ and $|+y\rangle$. We've started out talking about spin-${1\over 2}$, and in this first chapter of my textbook (*A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics* - Townsend) we are told that the definitions for $|+x\rangle$ and $|+y\rangle$ are

\begin{align}
|+x\rangle &= {1\over \sqrt{2}}|+z\rangle\ + \ {1\over \sqrt{2}}|-z\rangle \\
|+y\rangle &= {1\over \sqrt{2}}|+z\rangle\ + \ {i\over \sqrt{2}}|-z\rangle \, .
\end{align}

All of the calculations in this chapter involving these two states use these two equations, and one homework problem says to prove that a given state reduces to $|+x\rangle$ and $|+y\rangle$ that are "given in this chapter."
To me this seems like an implication that these state equations are always equal to what I've written above.
However this doesn't seem like it's right to me because we have only been talking about spin-${1\over 2}$ and there are other spins, and that they are a blanket statement for everything.

Are these the equations of state for only spin-${1\over 2}$ or is this true in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the spin-$1/2$ up states for the $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ directions.  They are always the same.  Of course, if you have different values of $S$, then you have more than just the spin-up and spin-down projections and the states are more complicated.

For instance, for $S=1$, we have 
$$
L_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and the state $\vert 11\rangle_x$, with $m_x=1$ (largest possible projection along $\hat x$) is a combination of the $\vert 1m\rangle_z$ states of projection $m_z$ 
$$
\vert 1 1\rangle_x=\frac{1}{2}\vert 11\rangle_z-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\vert 10\rangle_z+\frac{1}{2}\vert 1,-1\rangle_z
$$
There is also (of course) a $\vert 10\rangle_x$ and a state $\vert 1,-1\rangle_x$, and they are just the normalized eigenvectors of the matrix $L_x$ given above.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like $|11\rangle_x$ yet in my class. I didn't know that states could come as numbers, is that what that notation means?

Comment: $\vert SM\rangle$ is spin $S$ projection $M$.  In this notation your $\vert +x\rangle$ would be $\vert 1/2, +1/2\rangle_x$.  The key observation is that, for $S>1/2$, there is more than 2 possible states so just using $\pm z$  or $\pm x$ is not enough, hence the $M$ quantum number.

Comment: Oh, that does make a lot of sense. Is the subscript x saying that it's in the x direction? Edit: I read your answer again and saw that you said it's the largest possible projection along x.

Comment: @Grace yes the subscript $x$ or otherwise indicates the direction chosen for the projection of the state.